# adding a second conditional statement to an 'if' statement based on the value in a different dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, if-statement, conditional-statements

I currently have the following conditional:

```
if not tops_subset.eq(row.iloc[2:4]).all(axis=1).any():
```

For some background, it is from this code block:

```
tops_df = pd.read_csv('tops.csv', header=None)
tops_subset = tops_df.iloc[:, 2:4]
rows_written = 0

with open('for_email.csv', 'w', newline='') as for_email_file:
    for index, row in df_sorted_no_duplicates.iterrows():
        # Check if the third and fourth columns of the current row exist in 'tops.csv'
        if not tops_subset.eq(row.iloc[2:4]).all(axis=1).any():
```

It correctly checks if data in two columns already exist in any row of the file `tops.csv`

I want to modify if so that it accommodates a second condition. **The second condition is that `tops_subset.eq(row.iloc[2:4]).all(axis=1).any()` is true AND the value in the second from last column in the row in `tops.csv` where the data exist is 0.**

To be clear, I want the if statement to accept either:

1. The one it is already accepting which has the `not` statement

OR

2. The condition I described above

I am having trouble checking if the row where the data exists has a 0 in the second from last column. This is where I need help.

I have tried this:

```
if (tops_subset.eq(row.iloc[2:4]).all(axis=1).any() and tops_subset.iloc[:, -2].eq(0).any()) or not tops_subset.eq(row.iloc[2:4]).all(axis=1).any():
```

and this:

```
if (tops_subset.eq(row.iloc[2:4]).all(axis=1).any() and tops_subset.loc[tops_subset.eq(row.iloc[2:4]).all(axis=1), int(tops_subset.columns[-2])].eq(0).any()) or not tops_subset.eq(row.iloc[2:4]).all(axis=1).any():
```

Both don't work.